# Upgrade project to target .net framework to 4.7.2 without upgrading nuget references

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-framework-version

I have a solution with more than 50 projects, some are targeting .net framework 4.5 and some 4.
Primary executable project is targeting to 4.5.
I want to upgrade all projects to 4.7.2.

When project is upgraded from 4 to 4.7.2, I get message that some nuget packages are downloaded for .net 4 and should be downloaded again for 4.5 or 4.7.2, which I don't want to do because it triggers so many nuget upgrades and that's getting me into lots of compilation and dependency issues.

Basically, I would like to upgrade target framework of project, but keep nuget referring to older framework 4.(update nuget incrementally in future).

**Question:** Are there any downsides to this approach? Will nuget referring to mixed .net framework cause any issue?